# npm not found issue- Appium server start programmatically (Macbook M1)

Tags: node.js, npm, automation, path, appium

I am configuring appium like this:

```java
AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
    .withAppiumJS(
        new File("//usr//local//lib//node_modules//appium//build//lib//main.js")) 
    .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
    .usingPort(4723)
    .build();
```

But when I run I get this error:

```
[Appium] 'npm' executable is not found neither in the process working folder (/Users/.../eclipse-workspace/Appium) nor in any folders specified in the PATH environment variable (/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin).
```

Node and NPM are installed and I've checked the version.

My PATHs:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<..>/Library/Android/sdk
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.4/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/npm
export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
```

Comment: i made some changes in PATH 
now I am getting Output: [Appium] spawn ENOTDIR

Comment: May I know what was the solution for this? How it was fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency, As it worked for me.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```